# Adobe Scout no longer downloadable on 32-bit PCs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, profiler, adobe-scout

[Adobe Scout](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adobe.com%2Fdevnet%2Fscout%2Farticles%2Fadobe-scout-getting-started.html&ei=lfYrVd75Fs-JuATA6oHIBQ&usg=AFQjCNH-N05GoFWDY847cL6XxqFroKMSpQ&bvm=bv.90491159,d.c2E) is the breakthrough profiler for flash content, free from Adobe. However since a couple of months I am no longer able to download this app. It has disappeared from the Creative Cloud menu as well. It is no longer packaged with the Adobe Gaming SDK. When you click Download on its [official page](https://creative.adobe.com/products/scout), it simply brings the Creative Cloud app into focus, but nothing happens. There seems to be no way to acquire this app any more. Existing installs (older versions) show the error "this app has expired". Is there a way to download Scout CC for Windows? Has anyone got it working recently? How?

[image: scout nowhere]

Comment: scout is listed for me, some apps will not appear if they are incompatible with your system.

Comment: Make sure where it says "find new apps" that you're not filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scout will not list in Creative Cloud if you are on a 32-bit machine. Switch to a 64-bit machine (Windows or Mac) and then try to download it again.

The system requirements are:

- Microsoft Windows 7 (64-bit edition)
- Mac OS X v10.7 or v10.8 operating system

(credits go to [BotMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3491257/botmaster) for bringing this to my attention)